# Filemaker 13 Pro - Trying to create button labels from field entries

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to create dynamic buttons using the entries made in a field. I have a field called shows that contains show names. I want the button labels to reflect those names.

I have looked at using text fields as the labels and Set Field, but I cannot make a loop work to get the names.

Any help or direction is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a button for each **record** in your table, or does the field contain multiple **values** in each record? In general, the number of buttons cannot be dynamic, unless you put them in a portal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do something complicated where you do not need it.

I think, you have a field where you have a list of entries separated by carriage returns and you want every entry to appear as a label on a button.

In FileMaker 13 the default button label can not be calculated, so you will need to create buttons without labels and create and place the labels on top of them.

You will have to set labels to Insert/Merge.. and decide if you use calculated fields or global variables. You will need extra fields for calculating stored labels or you will need to populate your variables through the script.

To get the list item you can use GetValue() with a list (your field) and item number (starts at 1) as parameters.

As Michael mentioned, to make it dynamic you will have to use a portal, you are better off storing your labels as separate records.

Comment: Sorry... You're right Michael I wasn't quite clear. I am creating an audit database that starts with menus for the user to select their criteria.  So far it is three layouts with buttons. They click a button ok the first it sends them to the second based on what they chose. The third is a layout of the show names to be audited. This list will grow and change. So I made a related table for the show names but need the buttons to be able to change as the list does. I looked at using portals but ran into not knowing how to tell what the user chose and I kept running into multi user locking issues

Comment: The show buttons are literally only used set a variable and then navigate to the next layout.

Comment: @beretta819 IMHO, you should use a portal to show the available shows, and have a button in the portal that does Go to Related Record[].

Comment: The portal wouldn't be going to the record. All I need is to know what the user chose to assign it to a variable. Right now I have the 15 buttons that when clicked set the variable. Then they all go to the same audit layout where the variables are used to fill in the blanks for what they have chosen. The 15 buttons work except for when a show is added and then I need to add more buttons. Unless... Is there a way to setup a portal and know what the field contents they chose are. Like... The chose show 3. So the $show var is set to show 3 and then it navigates to audit layout.

Comment: @michael I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @beretta819 I am afraid this makes very little sense to me. I would suggest you join one of the Filemaker forums where this can be discussed in much wider scope than SO allows.

Comment: +1 to michael, I was typing out exactly the same thing. You are actually changing the topic of the post and the format here is different.